# Indirect modification of overloaded property WP_Post::$ancestors has no effect

Tags: posts

After updating my WordPress to the latest version, I'm getting the error below:

> *Indirect modification of overloaded property WP_Post::$ancestors has no effect*

```
 <ul id="mainwalker">
            <?php
            if(!$post->post_parent){
                $children = wp_list_pages(array(
                    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                    'title_li'    => '',
                    'echo'        => 1,
                    'walker' => new Sidebar_Custom_Walker()
                ));
            }else{
                if($post->ancestors)
                {
                    $ancestors = end($post->ancestors);

                    $children = wp_list_pages(array(
                        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                        'title_li'    => '',
                        'echo'        => 1,
                        'child_of'=>$ancestors,
                        'walker' => new Sidebar_Custom_Walker()
                    ));
                }
            }

            if ($children) { ?>
                <?php echo $children; ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, the property `WP_Post::$ancestors` is created dynamically. So, if you try to access to it when it doesn't exist, PHP calls the [magic method `__get` on that object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/__get/) and try to get the value of that property.

Because the property is dinamically created, you can not modify it like you do in this line (`end()` function modifies the internal pointer position of the array):

```
end($post->ancestors);
```

This message from PHP can be avoided if the `__get` method returns by reference, but you can not modify the core code (and I'm not sure if returning by reference in WP_Post::__get is appropiated anyway), so you should try to modify your own variable with post ancestors:

```
        if(!$post->post_parent){
            $children = wp_list_pages(array(
                'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                'title_li'    => '',
                'echo'        => 1,
                'walker' => new Sidebar_Custom_Walker()
            ));
        }else{

            $ancestors = $post->ancestors;
            // Using get_post_ancestors() should work as well
            // $ancestors = get_post_ancestors();

            if( !empty( $ancestors ) )
            {
                $ancestors = end($ancestors);

                $children = wp_list_pages(array(
                    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                    'title_li'    => '',
                    'echo'        => 1,
                    'child_of'=>$ancestors,
                    'walker' => new Sidebar_Custom_Walker()
                ));
            }
        }
```